# Later specifying of an array size in a struct type (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

So i have a bit of problem with c++.

I have a struct like this:

```
typedef struct{
    int n;
    int x[];
    int y[];
} MyStruct;
```

And my problem is that i can not figure it out how to specify the size of x,y array in a later function cause it is coming from an input and is not known before. It seems working as a dynamic one but i want it to be static.
BTW my variable from this struct is also an array.

E.g. in C# it worked something like this:

```
MyStructVariable[ (an index) ].x = new int[value];
```

I am new to c++ sorry if it is a trivial thing but i can not figure it out.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: So, you want to have dynamic array. `int* x;`, and then you may do `MyStruct value; value.x = new int[value]` (don't forget to `delete` it afterwards!). In addition to that, in C++, you don't need to typedef structs. Or, better, use C++ solution - `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I'd recommend `std::vector<int>` in first place.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yeah, thought about that, after I wrote my initial comment.

Answer (score 0):

> E.g. in C# it worked something like this:
>
> ```
> MyStructVariable[ (an index) ].x = new int[value];
> ```

C++ is different from C#, especially regarding handling of dynamic memory allocation.

What you want in C++ is a `std::vector<int>`

```
struct MyStruct {
    std::vector<int> x;
    std::vector<int> y;
    MyStruct(int value) : x(value), y(value) {}
};
```

or

```
struct MyStruct {
    int x;
    int y;
};

std::vector<MyStruct> myVector(mysize);
myVector[an index].x = value;
```